# What is the equivalent of a Java web application filter in an OSGi bundle?

Tags: osgi, security

Our application consists of multiple OSGi bundles, which expose their functionality through RESTful URIs. What is the best way to secure these URIs, so that only logged in and authorized users can access them? For a normal web application, I'd have used a web filter to control the access to all these URIs. Is there a way I can secure the access using just one security filter (or its equivalent) for all these URIs in OSGi? Or, will I need to include the security filter in each of the OSGi bundles? The container we are using is Apache Karaf, if it matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Apache Felix Http Jetty](https://www.jpm4j.org/#/p/org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.http.jetty/) service includes a filter facility. The easiest way to use it is to install the [Apache Felix Http Whiteboard](https://www.jpm4j.org/#/p/org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.http.whiteboard/) bundle and then register a Filter service ...

Unfortunately, this is not in the OSGi spec yet but will likely become part of the spec for the next round. I've been using this model for exactly your type of security now for 6 months and it works like a charm.

Comment: Thank you. I will check out the Http Whiteboard bundle.

Answer (score 2):

Another whiteboard-extender supporting this is Pax-Web.
But not only whiteboard, also if used with the std. OSGi http-service it supports filters and JSPs. Since version 2.0 it also supports servlet 3.0 anotations.
The next coming version of Pax-Web will also support only annotated Servlets in a Jar without web.xml. 
For more info take a look at http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxweb/Pax+Web